# Getting Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

We're using Nextjs/Reactjs as our FE and we have a server.js file that will allow us to upload image on `public/images/uploads` but for some reason whenever we run the server we are getting error `Cannot GET /`

Here is the code we have on server.js

```
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors');

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
var app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const appExpress = express();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
    const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl

    if (pathname === '/a') {
      app.render(req, res, '/a', query)
    } else if (pathname === '/b') {
      app.render(req, res, '/b', query)
    } else {
      handle(req, res, parsedUrl)
    }
  }).listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})

appExpress.use(express.static('public'))

let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'public/images/uploads')
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
  }
});
const upload = multer({ storage })

appExpress.use(cors());

appExpress.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  if (req.file)
    res.json({
      imageUrl: `images/uploads/${req.file.filename}`
    });
  else
    res.status("409").json("No Files to Upload.");
});

const PORT = 5000;

appExpress.listen(PORT);
console.log('api running on port: ' + PORT);
```

These are the scripts include on our package.json

```
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "server": "node server.js"
  },
```

Hoping to get some answers and recommendations. This codes are working locally without any issues

Comment: You don't have a GET route for `/` defined.  Who tried to `GET /`?

Comment: sorry, I want to get the build that came from reactjs/nextjs. Not sure what will be the adjustment. By the way this is working locally without any issue

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to get the build that came from reactjs/nextjs"?

Comment: Certainly this error doesn't come from just running the server.  Surely this must be an error that appears in the browser when you try and do something.  So what did you do in the browser to elicit the error?  Which endpoints did your browser try to access?  Was one of them the `/` endpoint?  If so, then why is it accessing an endpoint that you haven't implemented?  What code accessed the endpoint that doesn't exist?  If it's working locally, what are you doing to try and run it "not locally"?  Please provide debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a route for the GET /  like this:

```
appExpress.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({server: 'Running..!'});
});
```

Comment: Sorry, how can I run the build from reactjs/nextjs from there?